# Scat Identification on Upper Yosemite Falls Trail

Tags: yosemite, scat-identification

I meant to ask a Ranger before we left...

We saw this scat on the hike up to Columbia Point, which is 1/3rd of the way to Upper Yosemite Falls.  March 14 2017.  A warm couple weeks just after the big March snow storms.

I took a picture because everyone thought the bears were still mostly hibernating, so I thought I would check if it was recent bear activity.  Could be human or even dog?  It was just off the trail, so I'd hope not human!

I forgot scale was important, so I didn't intentionally include any clues -- the right-most dropping is on top of a twig which might help give a sense of scale.  There is also a fly on the middle one.

[image: Scat]
[image: Scat Zoomed]

Comment: Probably a dog or coyote.  If it was from a bear, there'd be bear bells in it, and it'd smell like bear spray.

Comment: Who is "everyone"?  The rangers?  I'm no scat-reader, but I wouldn't rule out bear solely on the basis of the mid-March date.  See https://www.nps.gov/yell/learn/nature/denning.htm.  Although this is about grizzlies in Yellowstone, it suggests that black bear might be out in a warm mid-March at lower latitudes.

Comment: I wasn't ruling them out, I was theorizing maybe the bears had started to come out.  Regardless, looking at coyoto scat online, I think this is dog.  Too consistent and no fur!

Comment: @Charlie Brumbaugh Yes, on leash.

Comment: ...and to confirm, we saw several leashed dogs that day on that trail.

Comment: Re dogs: I was just going to say "Oops, I was wrong" based on https://dogtrekker.com/yp/yosemite-national-park-yosemite-95389.

Comment: Definitely dog doo. Coyote scat is weird looking and always full of weird stuff.

Comment: @ab2 - You were right to second guess...dogs are not allowed on that trail, but frustratingly, people do it anyway. However, dogs are allowed on the lower falls trail. https://www.nps.gov/yose/planyourvisit/yosemitefallstrail.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on Olin Lathrop's suggestion, I searched around for coyote scat and found this resource:

https://www.wildlife.ca.gov/Conservation/Mammals/Gray-Wolf/Identification

It points out that dog scat (compared to coyote/wolf) doesn't have a tapered end and has a very consistent appearance due to commercial dog food.

Coyote (or wolf) would have a tapered end and would contain hair and possibly bone fragments.

Given the uniform consistency and shape, I'll suggest it is dog.

Comment: If you are not expecting other answers to show up and you are satisfied with it you can feel free to accept this answer. The comments suggest that a lot of other users agree that dog is the most likely.